# xAxes value missing on chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, chart.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/locug.png)

The value of xAxes are not showing at below of xAxes but the values are showing within the graph as per the image. I need to show all the values to be shown in the below xAxes of graph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `autoSkip` to false in the tick options:

```js
const options = {
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        autoSkip: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```